# How are connection points of an actor lifeline arranged?

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml, microsoft-visio-2016

I'm creating an UML Sequence diagram, and I'm wondering how the connection points of an actor lifeline are arranged (placed closer together compared to others).

[image: sequence diagram]

It seems to be rather random. The groups on the screenshot above has the following groups: 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2. It results in strange spacing between the messages.

Is it possible to influence the connection points? Simply having the same space between all of them would be good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be (another) bug caused by choosing Metric Units instead of US Units when creating a new document. The problem does not occur in documents with US Units.

See the answer by a Microsoft employee to [this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_visio-mso_winother/uml-lifeline-stencil-needs-more-connection-points/95c50dff-b65c-484a-97ba-12e872cc1413):

> Yes, I can repro this issue now and we have logged the bug for this issue which looks like is due to conversion from US to metric units.
>
> Meanwhile to work around this issue you can use US units and this issue will be resolved.